# Php regex return values within a pattern

Tags: php, regex, return

I'm looking for a regex to return the values in between Parameter("").

So for **1 + Parameter("MyVariable") + 36 * Parameter("Hello") + NoParameter("Nine")** it should return MyVariable and Hello. I already found a way to return the values between quotes, but this includes the NoParameter result as well. Any tips on how to integrate the Parameter() part?

```
<?php

$string     =   '1 + Parameter("MyVariable") + 36 * Parameter("Hello") + NoParameter("Nine")';

preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches); 

print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the substring `Parameter` as desired. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JKOZMN/1)

```
\bParameter\("\K[^"]+
```

- `\b` sets a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match

[Here is a PHP Demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/701358) with your updated code sample.
Of course you can also [use a capture group](https://regex101.com/r/JKOZMN/2) instead of `\K`.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm and now I already understand a bit better how it works!